# Is it legal to use anyType with an undefined XML namespace?

Tags: xml

We use GSoap to send SOAP requests, and process the responses. However, we've encountered a problem, because the distant server replies with XML containing the following:

<ax21:attributes xsi:type="axis2ns9259:anyType">

The ax21 namespace, AND the xsi namespace, are defined in an element above, which is fine (and xsi is the "standard" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"). However, the axis2ns9259 namespace is unknown (as far as I can tell - no mention of it anywhere in the document).
GSoap doesn't like it, and exits with an error, telling us that there is a type mismatch.

However, reading the XML specifications, it seems that the "anyType" type is present in ALL namespaces (and is, in fact, the "root" of that namespace's type hierarchy, the ur-type). This type accepts ANYTHING (any number of elements and/or attributes)

So, I'm wondering: Is GSoap too "strict", here, or should the server have defined this namespace, even if we should be able to know what this type is ?

We don't know if we should "correct" our code (that is, probably butcher GSoap so that it accepts this), or blame the server for sending incorrect XML (well-formed, but invalid - in fact, they don't even provide an XSD or DTD)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not schema-valid. The rules are in XML Schema 1.0 part 1 §3.3.4:

> 4 If there is an attribute information item among the element
>   information item's [attributes] whose [namespace name] is identical to
>   http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance and whose [local name] is
>   type, then all of the following must be true:
>
> 4.1 The ·normalized value· of that attribute information item must be ·valid· with respect to the built-in QName simple type, as defined by
>   String Valid (§3.14.4);

In your example, xsi:type is not a valid QName because the prefix has not been declared.

(I seem to remember having a lot of trouble with Axis-generated namespaces in the past.)

Comment: Please note, we're not in the context of an XML Schema definition, but in the context of a well-formed, but not "valid" XML Document, as it doesn't doesn't specify a DTD or XSD to validate it.

Is your answer true "everywhere" ? The document you refer to specifically describes XML Schema rules, so that's why I'm still in doubt.

Comment: As I said, the document is not valid according to the rules of the XML Schema specification. That's true whether or not there is a schema. But of course it's only relevant if you are using an application that cares about schema-validity.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, I have updated my question, because I think your answer might have hinged on the fact that I hadn't mentioned the xsi namespace (which is properly defined, to its "conventional" value: xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

Comment: We think the problem comes from the type which is declared in this element (that is, "axis2ns9259:anyType").

Should an XML processor assume that "<WhateverTheNamespace>:anyType" means "Anything goes" (even if that namespace wasn't declared), or should it first check that "<WhateverTheNamespace>" exists, and, ONLY THEN, IF the namespace exists, refer to the rule saying that, in any namespace, the "anyType" type is the "ancestor" of all types, to authorize anything (but , if the namespace wasn't defined, report an error) ?

Comment: A local name like "anyType" is meaningless without knowing what namespace it is in. You should never interpret a local name unless you have knowledge of the namespace.

Comment: So, even if the XML specification states that it is true in ANY namespace ?  Ok, in that case, I accept your answer :)

Comment: I don't know where you got the idea "it seems that the "anyType" type is present in ALL namespaces". You have misread something. The xs:anyType type is always available, but its name is Q{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType and it won't be recognized in any other namespace.

Comment: Oooh, thanks for correcting this misconception for me, Michael Kay. I re-read, and in fact, it is stated that it is only in the XSD namespace (xs:anyType). I guess that's the fact that it was "defined in every namespace" which I had not correctly understood.